Optimal solution for fetching data from a relational database with predicates
I have a springboot service calling a relational database, using Spring JPA or criteria.
Goal: Allow http paramaters to filter the DB results and return result in as JSON message
e.g. Get All countries where fields are active.
Problem:
When I left join the fields table to the country_rules tables and add a predicate to the field_join "where active = true", I get all the rows in country_rules as the left join matches the left table.
If I use a simple Join, if the fields or rules are not present then no rows are returned, but I want to show the country data.
Question
Should I amend my datamodel to being able to handle better filtering?
Should I get all the data from the DB and filter into DTO ?
Dont use JPA or criteria and create multiple DB queries to get the data I need?

SELECT
    dcr1_0.id,
    dcr1_0.country_id,
    dcr1_0.fields_id,
    dcr1_0.rules_id
FROM
    country_rules dcr1_0
    LEFT JOIN countries     c1_0 ON c1_0.id = dcr1_0.country_id
                                AND c1_0.active = true
    LEFT JOIN fields        f1_0 ON f1_0.id = dcr1_0.fields_id
                             AND f1_0.active = true
    LEFT JOIN rules         r1_0 ON r1_0.id = dcr1_0.rules_id
                            AND r1_0.active = true

[
  {
    "name": "United Kingdom",
    "twoLetterCode": "GB",
    "threeLetterCode": "GBR",
    "code": 826,
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "CREDITOR_ACCOUNT_NAME",
        "rules": [
          {
            "ruleType": "MANDATORY",
            "warningMessage": "Mandatory field is missing"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

Root<DbCountryRules> dcCountryRules = cq.from(DbCountryRules.class);
Join<DbCountryRules, DbCountries> countriesJoin = dcCountryRules.join("country",JoinType.LEFT);
Join<DbCountryRules, DbFields> fieldsJoin = dcCountryRules.join("fields",JoinType.LEFT);
Join<DbCountryRules, DbRules> rulesJoin = dcCountryRules.join("rules",JoinType.LEFT);

fieldsJoin.on(cb.equal(fieldsJoin.get("active"), true));
rulesJoin.on(cb.equal(rulesJoin.get("active"), true));

Question: Where fields and rules  can be disabled and enabled
